# The best way to filter DataFrame by column A, condition on column B and give out min values of column C

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am a newbie to python and pandas.

I want to get the `Y` values of every `peak` with the smallest `gap`

Here is my code so far which is very long and quite silly

```
for i in df.peaks.unique():
    min_y= df[df['peaks'] == i][df['gap'] == min(df[df['peaks'] == i]['gap'])]['y'].tolist()[0]
    print(min_y)
```

It works and this is the result:

```
171
204
246
278
311
416
```

Since, I saw some advanced syntax where people use `apply`, `map`, so they do not need to `loop`, can my task apply those techni ? Btw, I want to improve my code, please help!

The DataFrame is below for your informatin.

> ```
>       x    y   w   h  peaks   gap
> 0    79  171  13  14  178.0   7.0
> 1   155  171  14  14  178.0   7.0
> 2   213  170  14  15  178.0   8.0
> 3   281  171  14  14  178.0   7.0
> 4   337  171  14  14  178.0   7.0
> 5    78  203  14  14  211.0   8.0
> 6   209  204  14  14  211.0   7.0
> 7   287  204  15  14  211.0   7.0
> 8   365  204  14  13  211.0   7.0
> 9    78  236  14  14  251.0  15.0
> 10  156  246  14  13  251.0   5.0
> 11  232  246  14  14  251.0   5.0
> 12   79  277  14  14  284.0   7.0
> 13  166  278  14  14  284.0   6.0
> 14  243  278  13  14  284.0   6.0
> 15   79  303  14  14  316.0  13.0
> 16  144  310  15  13  316.0   6.0
> 17  216  310  13  14  316.0   6.0
> 18  292  311  14  13  316.0   5.0
> 19  370  311  14  14  316.0   5.0
> 20   80  405  14  14  420.0  15.0
> 21  157  414  13  14  420.0   6.0
> 22  226  414  14  14  420.0   6.0
> 23  303  416  14  13  420.0   4.0
> 24  374  416  14  14  420.0   4.0
> ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `groupby` and combine it with `idxmin`

```
data.loc[data.groupby('peaks')['gap'].idxmin(), 'y']

# 0     171
# 6     204
# 10    246
# 13    278
# 18    311
# 23    416
# Name: y, dtype: int64
```